# Audio clip is making no sound in Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform shootPoint;

public GameObject Bullet;

public float BulletSpeed;
public Animator anim;

private Vector2 direction;

public float fireRate;

private float ReadyForNextShot;

public GameManager gm;

public Player player;

public bool giga;

public GameObject Bullet1;

public AudioSource source;

public AudioClip shoot;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    direction = mousePos - (Vector2) shootPoint.position;
    FaceMouse();
    if (!gm.dialogue && !player.hasTransformed)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Time.time > ReadyForNextShot)
            {
                ReadyForNextShot = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
                Shooting();
            }
        }  
    }
}

void FaceMouse()
{
    shootPoint.transform.right = direction;
}
public void Shooting()
{
    if (giga)
    {
        GameObject bulletins = Instantiate(Bullet1, shootPoint.position, shootPoint.rotation);
        bulletins.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(bulletins.transform.right * BulletSpeed);
    }
    else if(!giga)
    {
        GameObject bulletins = Instantiate(Bullet, shootPoint.position, shootPoint.rotation);
        bulletins.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(bulletins.transform.right * BulletSpeed);
    }

    source.clip = shoot;
    print(source.isPlaying);
    anim.SetTrigger("shoot");
}
```

}
Just so you know the curly braces aren't properly alligned after copy and pasting the code.
So in this code I tell the audio source to change its clip to shoot. I have assigned the source variable and the clip as well as everything else. Though when in the game when shooting the audio source changes its clip to shoot but nothing is heard.

Comment: you dont show any code playing the clip only setting it

Answer (score 0):

> source.clip = shoot;

only assigns the clip property ... you also need to call [`source.Play()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html).

---

Alternatively to that, specifically for bullets, I would recommend to rather use [`source.PlayOneShot(shoot)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) instead which allows to play multiple instances of the sound in parallel.